# Android activity dropped event, application not responding

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contacts

I'm relatively new to android programming and I'm trying to write an application in which I want to start an activity from a BroadcastReceiver that is listening to the call state. In practice, I want to start an activity when a call is made. What I'm doing now is the following:

```
    public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        int state = telephony.getCallState();
...
  Intent i = new Intent(context, OnCallActivity.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        i.putExtras(bundle);

                        context.startActivity(i);

}
```

The activity started does nothing right now. I manage to start the activity without any problem, but what I get is an unresponsive app. The app is started, but the events like the back button don't work. I can press it several times without the application reacting and I have to kill it. In logcat here's what I see:

```
 11-02 13:54:19.651     918-1065/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ Asynchronous input event injection failed.
    11-02 13:54:19.651     918-1065/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because the current application is not responding and the user has started interacting with a different application.
```

Can you at least give me an hint to understand what can be blocking my application? I tried strict mode, but I got nothing significant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive? its not a good practice to start activity from a receiver or a service, you should use notifications to inform the user or a toast. Call activity is a high priority activity which has to be on top so that the user can receive or reject the call.

Comment: You are right and I had solved my problem (a couple of days ago)  like you said. This is a minor change in what is implemented but it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I decided to change the problem: I will just send a notification instead of launching an activity. This is the key to solve this as the high priority of the call activity seems to interfere with the application launched.